# How to get Dockerrun.aws.json set dynamic sourcePath based on environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In Elastic Beanstalk, code is uploaded to an S3 bucket and then mounted to `/var/app/current` in the EC2 instance so all the volumes need to be sourced from there.

So my `Dockerrun.aws.json` looks like this:

```
"volumes": [
    {
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/foo" // <<< problem lies here
      },
      "name": "foo"
    }
```

Because of this `/var/app/current` thing, doing `$ eb local run` fails because the source path on my local machine is `~/bar/foo` instead of `/var/app/current/foo` when deployed. The error is given below:

```
Mounts denied:
The path /var/app/current
is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.
```

Given that i want to have my eb deployments work locally and remotely with the same config file, how should I overcome this problem?

Stack:

- AWS Elastic Beanstalk Multi-container Docker
- MacOS, Docker for Mac

Answer (score 1):

By default Docker for Mac shared below paths

- /Users
- /Volumes
- /tmp
- /private

[image: Shared Volumes]

So if your path starts with any of these and you can keep both paths on local & AWS then it would work. Else you should share the `/var` on your Docker for Mac settings

Comment: This would be placing the application source code in my local machine in a folder called /var/app/current, where I would have to sudo everything i do in there. I created a symlink instead. Still looking for a more complete answer than this workaround.